# Make plot with varied line color for specific y values on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I want to make a plot such that for all `y` values greater than some `y0`, the plot will be shown in red. For all other values, it will be shown in blue. Is this possible in MATLAB? This would help draw distinct parts of a plot in different colors/settings for different conditions. I'm looking for something like

`plot(x,y,{y>y0,'-r'})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 plot(x,y,'b',x(y>y0),y(y>y0),'r');
```

Comment: also my first thought, plotted points are okay, but if the `y(y>y0)` elements are not consecutive in the original vector `y` you're plotting extra lines (eg only two maxima>y0 on each side of the dataset). Don't think there is a simple simple solution for that..

Comment: using plot this way draws a line between each two adjacent points in the order they are appear in the vector. If you want to sort the points just use `y=sort(y)` before... read more about sort here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html

Comment: Actually, you need to `[y,ix]=sort(y)` before, and then plot(x(ix),y) will be the the sorted order...

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the value which are greater than y0 and then plot the graph once for values less than y0 and second time for values greater than y0 by use of "hold on".

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html

Answer (score 0):

This question does not define what should happen at the limits.

But one good try is:

```
y1=y;
y1(y<=y0)=NaN;
plot(x,y,'b', x,y1,'r');
```